How to make PowerShell `Select-String` aka `sls` output exact match(es) only?
In a PowerShell script, I would like to check if a branch exists locally already, which I'm currently doing as $existsInLocal = (git branch | sls $branch) -ne $null, but that's incorrect because sls $branch matches line(s) containing $branch as a substring, but what I need is a version of sls $branch that outputs line(s) matching $branch exactly.
Is there a way to use ^ and $ to indicate start and end of line, respectively? My attempts at doing so didn't succeed.
I have looked at the Select-String documentation and didn't find a solution.
There's also an almost solution here that makes use of \b which matches a word boundary, but it doesn't work for my case because branch names can have \W chars (e.g. / or -). For example, \bjose/feature\b would match dev/jose/feature (the first \b matches the transition from / to j) or jose/feature/v2 or dev/jose/feature/v2.

I know there's another way to check for existence of local branch, but I really am mostly interested in sls exact matches in general, and the "determine whether local branch exists" use case is just one of many.

This works for me… $stdout = @( "main", "feature", "feature/abc", "feature/xyz" ); $stdout | select-string "^feature`$" - note you need to backtick-escape the $ in the branch pattern. If you have a concrete counter-example which isn’t working it would be useful to include it in your post. (Also, if you’re simply looking for an exact literal string with no regex patterns other than ^…$ you might as well use -contains rather than select-string)

Select-String -SimpleMatch?

echo there | select-string ^there$

@mclayton thanks, ^ and $ do indeed work with sls/select-string. My issue was that I wasn't accounting for the spaces that git branch prints before each branch name. The following worked for me git branch | sls ^\s*dev/jose$ from the command line and within a .ps1 script.

@iRon for me, using -SimpleMatch returned more than just exact matches; it also returned substring matches.

@mclayton git branch --contains dev/jose outputs   dev/jose\n  *master if I'm in the master branch; * dev/jose\n  master if I'm in the dev/jose branch; and    dev/jose\n  master if I'm any other branch. The variable output makes it not great for scripting. And git branch --contains dev/jos and git branch --contains dev/josev each output error: malformed object name dev/jos and error: ... dev/josev, respectively.

So select-string can match an exact pattern, you just needed to include the leading spaces.


To address your general question:

I really am mostly interested if sls (Select-String) finds exact matches in general.


Select-String by design looks for the given search term(s) as substring(s) in each input string (line).[1]

It also matches case-insensitively by default, in line with PowerShell's generally case-insensitive nature; use the -CaseSensitive switch as needed.


By default, each search term passed to the -Pattern parameter (possibly positionally, as the first unnamed argument) isinterpreted as a regex (regular expression).

To look for substrings literally (verbatim), add the -SimpleMatch switch.


There is no option to request whole-line matching, so the only way to achieve whole-line matching is indeed by using a regex with the ^ and $ anchors.

However, this may necessitate escaping a search term meant to be used literally, so that any characters that happen to be regex metacharacters aren't accidentally interpreted as such.

Use [regex]::Escape() to perform this escaping programmatically; in a literal search term, you may alternatively \-escape metacharacters individually.



By default, Select-String looks for all matches in the input file / among the input strings.

To make it only report the first match and stop searching for more, add the -List switch, but note that this only works with file input (either via -Path / -LiteralPath or by piping file-info objects via Get-ChildItem or Get-Item).

To make it only report a Boolean ($true or $false) depending on whether at least one match was found - which also stops searching after the first match - add the -Quiet switch instead.

Note: When piping strings to Select-String and no match is found, as of PowerShell 7.4.x there is unexpectedly no output instead of $false; this should be considered a bug - see GitHub issue #16681.
However, coercing this lack of output to a Boolean, e.g. in an if statement, is equivalent to $false, so this bug typically won't matter.


Additionally - and independently of -List - the -AllMatches  switch requests that the search term be matched as often as it occurs in each line (input string) rather than reporting just the first match.





Applied to your case:
$existsInLocal = git branch | sls -Quiet ('^\s*{0}$' -f [regex]::Escape($branch))


The above demonstrates the escaping technique, even though it's probably not necessary in your case, and, per your feedback matches \s*, i.e. optional whitespace before the branch name.

-Quiet makes Select-String output $true if a match was found (see above), and also stops searching in that case - this obviates the need for your (...) -ne $null test, which, incidentally, is generally better written as $null -ne (...) - see the relevant PSScriptAnalzyer rule



Taking a step back:
As mclayton notes, a simpler solution for literal whole-line matching is possible, using the -contains operator:
$existsInLocal = (git branch) -contains $branch


PowerShell automatically relays an external program's stdout output line by line and by enclosing the call in (...) and using that with an operator, the lines are collected in an array (assuming two or more output lines).

-contains then performs element-by-element equality comparisons on this array (essentially, -eq operations with each array element as the LHS) until a match (at most one) is found, in which case $true is returned (otherwise $false). In the case at hand, this amounts to literal, whole-line comparisons.

Note: -contains too is case-insensitive by default, but you can use the case-sensitive operator variant, -ccontains.



The only potential down-side of this approach is that it requires collecting all stdout lines in memory, up front before matching is performed, whereas the streaming nature of a Select-String-based pipeline solution allows stopping as soon as a match is found.
With only a limited amount of stdout output, such as in the case at hand, this won't be a problem, however.

[1] The typical use case is that Select-String receives text line by line, such as by making it search a file using -Path / -LiteralPath or when piping the output of an external program to it.
However, when you pass a multiline string as a single object to it (e.g. by piping Get-Content -Raw to it), that string is searched through as a whole, enabling cross-line matching.

Rewriting your regex may be all you need. The following is working for a random string with slashes and dashes (thanks to mklement0 for pointing out the simplification).
^[-/\w]+$

Some explanation:

[]+ defines a list of characters to match, which can be repeated one or more times
/ matches a slash
- matches a dash
\w matches a word characters (you found that already)
^ and $ will match the beginning and end of a line (again, something you found out already)

So the inner capture within the list will match on any word character, a slash or a dash. If you repeat this one or more times and include the start and end of line, it will match the pattern you explained.

Thx for the explanation @mklement0 I have updated my answer to show your regex string in case someone finds this question in the future.
